# How to select only last X values where column value changed

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select (MySQL) last for example 5 rows where value in NOTE field has changed, by every distinct ID?

Example:

```
    CREATE TABLE `LOGTABLE` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ITEM_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DATETIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `TYPE` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `NOTE` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    ALTER TABLE `LOGTABLE`
  MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
COMMIT;

    INSERT INTO `LOGTABLE` (`ID`, `ITEM_ID`, `DATETIME`, `TYPE`, `NOTE`) VALUES
(2, 167, '2021-06-15 16:47:23', 0, 'T'),
(3, 168, '2021-06-15 16:48:11', 0, 'F'),
(4, 167, '2021-06-15 16:59:51', 0, 'T'),
(5, 168, '2021-06-15 17:00:48', 0, 'F'),
(6, 167, '2021-06-15 17:12:19', 0, 'T'),
(7, 168, '2021-06-15 17:13:25', 0, 'T'),
(8, 167, '2021-06-15 17:24:47', 0, 'F'),
(9, 168, '2021-06-15 17:26:02', 0, 'F'),
(10, 167, '2021-06-15 17:37:15', 0, 'T');
```

And I want to have this result:

```
167- IDs 2,8,10
168- IDs 3,7,9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Lag` function and `Cte` table as follows:

```
WITH Cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           LAG(Note,1) OVER(PARTITION BY Item_ID ORDER BY Id) PrevNote
    FROM [dbo].[LOGTABLE]
),   
Final AS(
    SELECT *,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ITem_ID ORDER BY ID DESC) rnk 
    FROM Cte AS c
    WHERE Note <> ISNULL(PrevNote,'')
)
SELECT * 
FROM final
WHERE rnk <= 5
ORDER BY ITem_ID
```

It gives you result below:

```
ID  ITEM_I  DATETIME    TYPE      NOTE  PrevNote    rnk
10  167 2021-06-15 17:37:15.000 0   T   F            1
8   167 2021-06-15 17:24:47.000 0   F   T            2
2   167 2021-06-15 16:47:23.000 0   T   NULL         3
9   168 2021-06-15 17:26:02.000 0   F   T            1
7   168 2021-06-15 17:13:25.000 0   T   F            2
3   168 2021-06-15 16:48:11.000 0   F   NULL         3
```

It returns Maximum 5 rows for each Item_Id That has changed

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I think MySQL does not support LAG function?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

> ```
> select item_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) Ids
> from (
> select *, case when NOTE <> LAG(NOTE,1,'X') over (partition by item_id order by datetime) then 1 else 0 end lnote
> from LOGTABLE
> ) t
> where lnote = 1 
> group by item_id
> ```
>
> ```
> item_id | Ids   
> ------: | :-----
>     167 | 2,8,10
>     168 | 3,7,9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4bb75cd868bc8beb26597ef72a58bac7)*